# how to echo a imagepath and append it after ajax success function in codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I want to echo my image path using append and also using a variable to store the value but when i do it shows me error let me show you my code.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){

        var lastID = $('.load-more').attr('lastID');

        if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height() && lastID != 0){
            jQuery.ajax({
                type:'POST',

                url:'<?php echo base_url("user/get_all_post"); ?>',
                 data: "id=" + lastID,
                    dataType: 'json', 


                beforeSend:function(html){
                    $('.load-more').show();
                },
                success:function(data){
                       var ParsedObject = JSON.stringify(data);            
                       var json = $.parseJSON(ParsedObject);

                        $PostId=json[4]['id'];


                        for(i=0;i<5;i++ )
                      {

                            var post_status = json[i]['status'];
                            var status_image = json[i]['status_image'];
                            var multimage = json[i]['multimage'];

                            //           alert($status_image);               


                             $("#status_data").append('<div style=" margin: 20px 50px 0px 40px; "><a><?php echo img($user_image); ?></a><a><?php echo $uname; ?></a><div>'+post_status+'</div></div>');

                             $("#status_data").append('<div style=" margin: 20px 50px 0px 40px; "><a><?php echo img($user_image); ?></a><a><?php echo $uname; ?></a><div><img src='+<?php base_url('uploads/'.status_image); ?>+'></div></div>');

                            $('#status_image_data').attr('src',status_image);


                      }


                       $('.load-more').attr('lastID', $PostId);


                    }


            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

now here the image is not showing its correct path even if i save the value of status_image in a variable let me show you that too

[image: image of firebug]

now here the path is showing itself in user but the images are stored in uploads how can i access that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct

**From**

```
$("#status_data").append('<div style=" margin: 20px 50px 0px 40px; "><a><?php echo img($user_image); ?></a><a><?php echo $uname; ?></a><div><img src='+<?php base_url('uploads/'.status_image); ?>+'></div></div>');
```

**To**

```
$("#status_data").append('<div style=" margin: 20px 50px 0px 40px; "><a><?php echo img($user_image); ?></a><a><?php echo $uname; ?></a><div><img src="<?php echo base_url('uploads'); ?>/'+ status_image +'"></div></div>');
```

In short, you can't combine js variable with php,

**From**

```
<img src='+<?php base_url('uploads/'.status_image); ?>+'>

                                    ^
You will receive PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant status_image - assumed 'status_image'
```

**To**

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url('uploads'); ?>/'+ status_image +'">
```

Comment: Thank you for the help i got it .

Comment: just wanted to ask a little something that if i want to echo multiple images together what can i do then? @Akshay Hegde

Comment: @HimanshuGoyal: You need another img tag and and just `echo` or else loop it if you have list of `src` in array